# Apply Maximum Condition with Join

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I am getting data from two tables by left joining them, I have to get a specific record on base of its Maximum Value,this is my query

```
select t1.Id,t2.LastModifiedDate,t2.TypeId
        from Table1 t1 
        Left join Table2 t2 
        on t1.Id=t2.Id and (t2.Disabled=0 and t2.TypeId not in (1,3,5))
        where 
        t2.TypeId =8
```

and this is my Tables structure

```
  t1 ==> Id Name Age
  t2 ==> TransactionId TypeId LastModifiedDate Disabled Id
```

I have to apply condition like this in Where clause

```
t2.TypeId =8 and (t2.TransactionId=Max(TransactionId) and t2.Disabled=1)
```

How can I get the Maximum TransactionId of the specific typeId?
ie Pass Maximum TransactionId only if its typeId is 8 and disabled=1

Comment: what DB you use? Oracle?

Comment: @SyedSalmanRazaZaidi Best if you add the RDBMS as a tag (sql-server-2008)

Comment: Please share table schema & sample date with desired output.

Comment: Condition of getting MAX() can be achieved using CROSS APPLY , but I am not clear with your requirements yet!

Comment: @AK47 I have shared the schema

Comment: @TT.Thanks I will take care next time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a subquery to get the maximum transactionID for a particular TypeID.

```
SELECT t1.Id, LastModifiedDate, TypeID
FROM Table1 t1
LEFT JOIN Table2 t2 ON t1.Id=t2.Id
WHERE (t2.Disabled=0 AND t2.TypeID NOT IN (1,3,5))
AND t2.TypeId=8
AND t2.TransactionId=
    (SELECT MAX(TransactionID) FROM Table2 t3 WHERE t3.TypeID=t2.TypeID)
```

The subquery in the last line uses Table2 and gives it a new alias ("t3") so you can give it a condition  that refers to the TypeID from "t2" in the main query.
I may not have understood exactly what you're trying to do here, but the point is that what you probably want can be accomplished with a subquery.

It's possible that if all you want is the latest transaction for a certain account, you could simplify this greatly by simply SELECTing the transactions, ORDER BY the transactionID DESCending, and just take the first result (i.e. `LIMIT 1` or `TOP 1` depending on DBMS).

Comment: Thanks for answering,I want if TypeId=8 and it has Maximum Value of Transaction,then Pass it in Query, Let me try your solution